# Total sum of has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not new to Ruby on Rails, but never really worked with more complicated ActiveRecord queries.

Say I have a Affiliate model that has_many referred users and referred users has_many purchased_products.

What I want to do is an efficient ActiveRecord way of getting the total sum of the count of purchased_products of all the referred users. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming objects like:

```
class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  #should have purchased_products_count integer column
  belongs_to :affiliate
  has_many :pruchased_products
end

class PurchasedProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :purchased_products_count
end

products_count = User.first.purchased_products.size # uses counter_cache to get the size
another_products_count = User.first.purchased_products_count # get the value diretly
all_users_products_count = my_affiliate.users.map(&:purchased_products_count).inject(:+) # makes an array of product counts then sums them
```

I think this might also work

```
my_affiliate.users.sum('purchased_products_count')
```

Comment: I already have a solution similar to this, I'm looking for an ActiveRecord solution to do the calculation in the database, instead of with Ruby.

EDIT: Sorry didn't see the last line. Not sure if we want to add another column, would it be possible to do purchased_products.count instead of having that cached column?

Comment: The counter cache is far more efficient, which is what you wanted, since it's just reading a column instead of having to do a count(*) and loop through every row of the table.

Comment: Will the counter_cache automatically increment/decrement appropriately?

Comment: Also what if I want to do the sum of only purchased_products that were created_at Time.now.beginning_of_month, for example?